# Url from string in Angular 9

Tags: angular, string, url

I am new to Angular9, I need to extract the substring

`src=/sites/default/files/text_images/cover/gita.jpg`

(inside the `img` tag as seen in the string).

Then I need to construct a new url: 
http://12.23.34/sites/default/files/text_images/cover/gita.jpg

Please let me know how can I do it.

The following is the long string.

```
"\n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_formatter' -->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->\n  \n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image' -->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->\n<img src=\"/sites/default/files/text_images/cover/gita.jpg\" alt=\"Bhagavad Gita\" typeof=\"foaf:Image\" />\n\n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->\n\n\n\n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->\n\n",
```

Comment: If it's a fixed string then, `input.split('=')[1].split('"')[1]`

Comment: I don't understand the question, what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try like the below example..

```
var str = "<img alt='' src='http://facebook.com' /><br/>Sample string<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>";

var regex = /<img.*?src='(.*?)'/;
var src = regex.exec(str)[1];

console.log(src);
```